# Updating table rows in datatables with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

How can I use `jQuery ajax` to handle `checked` checkboxes? How do I then send each `checked` checkbox in the html table, to `ajax.php`?

This is what I've tried so far:

`ajax.php`

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['to']) && isset($_SESSION['user']['id'])) {
    if (is_numeric($_POST['id']) && is_numeric($_POST['to'])) {
        include("mysql_connector.php");
        $user = $_SESSION['user']['id'];
        $sendTo = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['to']));
        foreach ($_POST['id'] as $id) {
            $id = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($id));
            mysql_query("UPDATE `email` SET status = '$sendTo' WHERE `email_id` = '$id' AND `userid` = '$user'");
        }
    }
}
```

`Javascript:`

```
$(".submit").click(function() {
    var id = $("#id").val();
    var to = $("#bins").val();
    var dataString = 'id=' + id + '&to=' + to;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: dataString,
    });
});
```

`html:`

```
<form method="POST">
    <table id="inventory" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" name="checkall" id="checkall" onclick="checkAll(this)" class="checkall">Check All</a></th>
                <th>Time Received</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>ID</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="email">
                <td style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" name='msg[]' class="id" value="2" /></td>
                <td>1231231</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="email">

                <td style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" name='msg[]' class="id" value="3" /></td>
                <td>1231231</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>1</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
    </br>
    <select name="bins" class="bins">
        <option value="1">Archive</option>
        <option value="2">Read</option>
        <option value="3">Unread</option>
        <option value="4">Save</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="move" value="Move" class="submit" style="width:auto;"/>
</form>
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: This post can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090055/handling-array-field-post-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is invalid to have multiple dom elements with **duplicate ids**.  If those checkboxes need ids, make them unique.  If they don't need ids, then just drop them completely.

---

To get a list of the values of all checked checkboxes, do:

```
var checkedVals = [];
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
    checkedVals.push($(this).val());
});
```

Or you can fetch different groups of checkboxes by name:

```
var checkedMsgVals = [];
$("input[name='msg[]']:checked").each(function() {
    checkedMsgVals.push($(this).val());
});
```

To send these to php, just include them in your data packet when you make the call.  To do this you'll want to send an object over, not a querystring.

```
var dataObj = {'id': id, 'to': to, 'checkedValues': checkedMsgVals };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    data: dataObj,
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice and letting me know about the duplicate ids. ^.^  Thanks Adam for the help.